# Input shape for CNN and LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I would like to train CNN + LSTM model to drive a car using CNN + LSTM using this code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalMaxPool2D, Flatten, Dropout, Dense, TimeDistributed, GRU, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

def vgg(input_shape, num_classes):

    # create a VGG16 "model", we will use
    # image with shape (224, 224, 3)
    vgg = VGG16(
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet',
        input_shape=(200, 160, 3)
    )
    # do not train first layers, I want to only train
    # the 4 last layers (my own choice, up to you)
    for layer in vgg.layers[:-4]:
        layer.trainable = False
    # create a Sequential model
    model = Sequential()
    # add vgg model for 4 input images (keeping the right shape
    model.add(
        TimeDistributed(vgg, input_shape=(4, 200, 160, 3))
    )
    # now, flatten on each output to send 5 
    # outputs with one dimension to LSTM
    model.add(
        TimeDistributed(
            Flatten()
        )
    )
    model.add(LSTM(256, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
    # finalize with standard Dense, Dropout...
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

This is my main code

```
# Splitting data into a training set and test set
train_data = np.load("/mydrive/Mister_car/training_data-1.npy", allow_pickle=True)
train = train_data[:]
test = train_data[:]

print(np.shape(train[5]))

X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, 4, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
Y = np.array([i[1] for i in train])#.reshape(-1, 9)

x_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, 4, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
y_test = np.array([i[1] for i in test])#.reshape(-1, 9)

# start training
model.fit(x=X,
          y=Y,
          epochs=10,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
          )

# save the whole model
model.save(MODEL_DIR)
```

I have an array and each element in this array has 2 elements:
array [0] is a sequance of 4 images with shape (200,160,3)
array [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLRQH.jpg) is an array with 9 elements

But I get the following error after last epoch while the model is saving

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `TimeDistributed()` wrapper around `vgg`, because what it does is add another dimension. So, you end up with 5 instead of 4, which is causing the error. Also remove the -1 in this line:

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, 4, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3)
```

Beyond that, some parts of your code are missing. If you provide them I'll be able to help with more certainty.